# Apply animation to Slick Slides

Tags: javascript, html, css, frontend, css-animations

I would want to apply the transition between those images to my Slick slide so I can control.

The sample of the animation ( Basically a fade and move in the same time ): https://jsfiddle.net/bg90fayo/

My slick slide : https://jsfiddle.net/L6qjpky4/3/

```
<body>
    
    <div class="my-slide-container">
        
        <div id="top-slider" class="my-slide-wrapper">
            <img class="slide slide00" src="https://dummyimage.com/300x180/ff0000/ffffff.jpg&text=Slide+1">
            <img class="slide slide01" src="https://dummyimage.com/300x180/00ff00/000000.jpg&text=Slide+2">
            <img class="slide slide02" src="https://dummyimage.com/300x180/0000ff/ffffff.jpg&text=Slide+3">
        </div>
        
        <div id="bottom-slider" class="my-slide-wrapper">
            <img class="slide slide00 main"  style="animation-delay: 0s;  animation-fill-mode: forwards; opacity:0;" src="https://i.imgur.com/x3dgNKQ.jpg">
            <img class="slide slide01 main"  style="animation-delay: 4s;  animation-fill-mode: forwards; opacity:0; display: block; visibility: visible;" src="https://i.imgur.com/RCOaeIE.jpg">
            <img class="slide slide02" src="https://dummyimage.com/300x180/0000ff/ffffff.jpg&text=Image+3">
        </div>
        
    </div>
    
</body>
```

CSS

```
.my-slide-container {
    margin: 30px;
}

.my-slide-wrapper, .my-image-wrapper {
    margin: 0 auto;
    max-width: 300px;
}

img {
    max-width: 300px;
    width: 100%;
}

.slick-dots li {
    margin: 0;
}

.slick-next::before,
.slick-prev::before {
    color: #000;
    opacity: 1;
}

.my-image {
    visibility: hidden;
    position: absolute;
}

#myImage00 {
    visibility: visible;
}

.im-hiding {
    visibility: hidden;
}

.im-showing {
    visibility: visible;
}

  @keyframes fade-in-move-down {
    0% {
      opacity: 0;
      transform: translateX(2rem);
    } 
    100% {
      opacity: 1;
      transform: translateX(0);
    }
  }
  
    .main{
    animation: fade-in-move-down 1.2s;
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
    display: block;
    visibility: visible;
  }
  
    .slide .slick-active img{
        visibility: visible;
    }
```

JS

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $('#top-slider').slick({
        asNavFor: '#bottom-slider',
        dots: true,
        infinite: false,
        speed: 1,
        slidesToShow: 1,
        slidesToScroll: 1
    });
    
    $('#bottom-slider').slick({
        arrows: false,
        dots: false,
        fade:true,
        draggable: false,
        infinite: false,
        speed: 1,
        slidesToShow: 1,
        slidesToScroll: 1,
        waitForAnimate: false,
    });
    
});
```

The wanted transition between the slides :

```
body{
  background-color:black;
}
  
  
  @keyframes fade-in-move-down {
    0% {
      opacity: 0;
      transform: translateX(2rem);
    } 
    100% {
      opacity: 1;
      transform: translateX(0);
    }
  }
  
    .main{
    animation: fade-in-move-down 1.2s;
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
    display: block;
    visibility: visible;
  }
```

Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

You can do that with slick parameters:

```
$('#top-slider').slick({
  asNavFor: '#bottom-slider',
  dots: true,
  infinite: false,
  speed: 1,
  autoplay: true,
  autoplaySpeed: 2000,
  slidesToShow: 1,
  slidesToScroll: 1
});
```

You can adjust it for you needs - read more [here](https://kenwheeler.github.io/slick/).

Edit as per comment:

You need to set animation to the active slide selector:

```
.slick-active { animation: fade-in-move-down 1.2s; }
```

In order to set the animation only to the second slider you can:

```
#bottom-slider .slick-active { animation: fade-in-move-down 1.2s; }
```

Comment: slick parameters only allow for a normal fade. I need a fade AND a move from the right at the same time.

Comment: Thank you for your input. Your code does actually make the transition but for both of the slides, I just need it for the bottom one. Also the fade restarts at a blank background, i need the new image to come on top of the other one, kinda overlapping it. Like in this https://jsfiddle.net/bg90fayo/

Comment: Really close, just need the images to stay on top of each other https://jsfiddle.net/r429k6mh/2/

Comment: As you can see the main difference between the wanted fiddle to yours is the `position absolute`. Since you use slick slider your markup is different. you can tweak your existing code to do more of the same (as you already did with your latest fiddle).

Comment: Oh, and for the second slide selector change `.slick-active {...`  to this: `#bottom-slider .slick-active {...`. And you can also change the `@keyframe` to start with `opacity: 0.1`.